# Deploy Office Add-In for Excel with Office Store Globally Disabled?

Tags: microsoft-office-365, microsoft-excel

I have been struggling for ~5 months to get help on GitHub as I'm unable to deploy my Office-JS App via out internal MS365 Admin Center.

Most recently, my question/concern is if it **is possible to deploy a "custom/Admin Managed" app while having access to the "Office Store" disabled globally?**

- Based on below quote under "update", I suppose I have two questions/tests
- Can you deploy an app from the store using MS365 Admin Center while having Store Disabled
- Can you deploy a "custom" app while having access to Store disabled

Note: I've been using this for testing custom app [manifest.xml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-samples/main/Samples/excel-shared-runtime-scenario/manifest.xml?_sm_au_=isVq47fT5fN0nFsVpFRfjKsp6JGjM)

Can anyone confirm this for me?

https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/3214

[image]

Note: Our IT department does have Outlook Add-Ins from the store deployed to end users, but they also don't have the store disabled for Outlook, not sure if that helps, but thought I'd share. I'm going crazy trying to understand the issue, one thing I've done to test is simply to try deploying a manifest straight from GitHubs Office-JS [Sample Manifests](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-samples/main/Samples/excel-shared-runtime-scenario/manifest.xml?_sm_au_=isVkMs5qRJ0H0KTMpFRfjKsp6JGjM), but it still doesn't work, so its not MY manifest that is the issue.

Update:

- I read the following in the docs, which is what I'd expect, that you CAN deploy custom apps while simultaniously disabling the store, but I'd still like to have somebody answer whom has an actual environment setup to test in... Also note, below says "from the store" not "custom app".

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/manage/manage-addins-in-the-admin-center?view=o365-worldwide#prevent-add-in-downloads-by-turning-off-the-office-store-across-all-apps-except-outlook

> This does not prevent an administrator from using Centralized Deployment to assign an add-in from the Office Store.

I also read this, which I know to be incorrect, so my faith in the docs is limited...

> Preventing users from accessing the office store will also prevent them from Sideloading Office Add-ins for testing from a network share.